# RequestTracker on Ubuntu 10.10 server. Apache won't start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, request-tracker

Having issues getting RT to run on Ubuntu.  I followed the steps [here](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/WithEmailFacility) but am running into a problem where apache doens't start after pasting in the following lines in the sites-available/default file.

```
Include /etc/request-tracker3.8/apache2-modperl2.conf
RedirectMatch ^/$ /rt
```

The apache2 error log has the following line.

```
[Wed Feb 02 11:14:25 2011] [error] Can't locate Apache/DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/share/request-tracker3.8/lib /usr/share/request-tracker3.8/lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl . /etc/apache2) at (eval 4277) line 3.\n
```

I'm guessing (hoping actually) that this is a simple fix, but I'm kind of lost.

Thanks,

Comment: "RT"? I guess "RT on U-u 10x2 srv apch w't s" would be a lot clearer subject line for your question.

Comment: @poige  RT (Request Tracker) is a ticketing product by Best Practical, it's pretty common in Unix shops (http://bestpractical.com/rt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a simple error: You either don't have the Apache::DBI perl module installed, or it's not in Perl's @INC search path.

Make sure that the `libapache-dbi-perl` package is installed (`apt-get install libapache-dbi-perl`) -- This should probably be a dependency of any RT packages, but it's possible it was left out.
If the package is installed find out where it's putting itself by using `dpkg -L libapache-dbi-perl` and ensure that it's in the perl @INC path list.

Comment: If you installed RT using apt and this package wasn't installed as a dependency you may want to let the RT package maintainer know so they can fix it for the future.

Comment: I actually used the install from the wiki.  http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/WithEmailFacility  Can you install using sudo apt-get?  That would have made my life much easier.

Comment: @Dayton There is an apt package for Request Tracker, though I don't know how good it is / how up to date it is.  In my case RT is something I would install on my own because its strength is that it can be customized extensively and apt packages tend to make that difficult, but if you just need the basic functionality of a ticket system the apt package may be worth looking at.